# How to translate TimeSpan calculations to SQL via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having an entity with a `TimeSpan` property (`Start`) and an `int` (`Duration` in *minutes*) property.

I want to perform a linq query that will fetch all the rows that apply to the following logic:

`Start <= DateTime.Now <= Start + Duration`

My LINQ

```cs
from n in _context.Notifications
where n.Start <= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= n.Start.Add(new TimeSpan(0, n.Duration, 0))
select n;
```

translates into (as taken from the SQL Server Profiler)

```sql
SELECT [n].[Id], [n].[Active], [n].[Created], [n].[Day], [n].[Duration], [n].[Name], [n].[Start], [n].[Type]
FROM [Notifications] AS [n]
WHERE [n].[Start] <= CAST(GETDATE() AS time)
```

The warning that I'm getting from the EntityFramework Core is

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'where 
>   (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= [n].Start.Add(new TimeSpan(0, [n].Duration, 0)))' >could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

The SQL query that I want is this

```sql
SELECT [n].[Id], [n].[Active], [n].[Created], [n].[Day], [n].[Duration], [n].[Name], [n].[Start], [n].[Type]
FROM [Notifications] AS [n]
WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) BETWEEN [n].[Start] AND DATEADD(MINUTE, [n].[Duration], [n].[Start])
```

Comment: Unrelated to the Problem: You can do `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(n.duration)` - Seems more readable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: do not run the calculation as part of the LINQ query. Do the timespan first, then run 2 datetiime instances in as parameters. Done.

Comment: I do not understand. How to do the timespan calculations without the `Start` and `Duration` data?

Comment: Sorry @Dimitris, some people don't read carefully questions before answering/voting. This is a standard answer for a different scenario which apparently does not apply to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the EF SQL Functions?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions?view=efcore-3.1

Unfortunately I don't see a mix of DateTimeOffset & Timespan function but possibly you could make what's there work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
            var r = _context.Notifications.Select(item => new
            {
                item,
                start = item.Start,
                finish = SqlFunctions.DateAdd("SECOND", (item.Duration * 60), item.Start)
            }).Where(x => x.finish.HasValue && x.start <= dt && dt <= x.finish.Value).Select(x => x.item);
```